# Check if two classes have the same superclass

Tags: java, superclass, instanceof

I was trying to know if any two classes share the same superclass using the following method

```
private boolean sameSuperclass(Class<?> leftClass, Class<?> rightClass) {
    if(rightClass.getClass() instanceof leftClass.getSuperclass()) //I've also used leftClass.getSuperclass().name()
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: do you mean leftClass is super class of rightClass , or leftClass ,rightClass has superclass some A ?

Comment: You can compare `Class` objects with `equals()`. Also take a look at [`isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Apply `java.lang.Class#isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)` twice on super-class instance. Although, it will be positive even if superclass isn't a direct superclass, not sure if it desirable for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Generic Superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass%28%29):

```
    private static boolean sameSuperclass(Class<?> leftClass, Class<?> rightClass) {
        if(rightClass.getGenericSuperclass().equals(leftClass.getGenericSuperclass()))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sameSuperclass(Integer.class,Float.class)); //true
        System.out.println(sameSuperclass(TreeMap.class,ArrayList.class)); //false
    }
```

Comment: You should really use `equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: what if I don't want the direct superclass?

Comment: Eventually every class will have `Object` as superclass. So if you don't want a direct superclass then what specifically are you looking at?

Comment: Nevermind, I've found out a bug in my code and the above solution works just fine. Thanks